# Why does FetchContent say "no download info" even with GIT_REPOSITORY?

Tags: cmake

This is my first time using `FetchContent` in CMake 3.11 and it doesn't seem to notice that I'm giving it a Git repository:

```
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/ExternalProject.cmake:2525 (message):
  No download info given for 'gsl-populate' and its source directory:

   C:/Dev/foo/build/gsl-src

  is not an existing non-empty directory.  Please specify one of:

   * SOURCE_DIR with an existing non-empty directory
   * DOWNLOAD_COMMAND
   * URL
   * GIT_REPOSITORY
   * SVN_REPOSITORY
   * HG_REPOSITORY
   * CVS_REPOSITORY and CVS_MODULE
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/ExternalProject.cmake:3100 (_ep_add_download_command)
  CMakeLists.txt:13 (ExternalProject_Add)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Dev/foo/build/gsl-subbuild/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".

CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FetchContent.cmake:786 (message):
  CMake step for gsl failed: 1
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FetchContent.cmake:822 (__FetchContent_directPopulate)
  cmake/FetchGSL.cmake:21 (FetchContent_Populate)
  CMakeLists.txt:29 (include)
```

The `FetchGSL.cmake` script is:

```
include("FetchContent")

set(GSL_GIT_REPOSITORY "https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL.git"
  CACHE STRING "C++ Guideline Support Library Git repository URL")

set(GSL_GIT_TAG "d846fe50a3f0bb7767c7e087a05f4be95f4da0ec"
  CACHE STRING "C++ Guideline Support Library Git commit ID, branch, or tag")

mark_as_advanced(GSL_GIT_REPOSITORY GSL_GIT_TAG)

FetchContent_Declare(
  "gsl"
  GIT_REPOSITORY "${GSL_GIT_REPOSITORY}"
  GIT_TAG "${GSL_GIT_TAG}"
  GIT_SHALLOW 1
)

FetchContent_GetProperties("gsl")

if(NOT gsl_POPULATED)
  FetchContent_Populate("gsl" QUIET)
  add_library(GSL::GSL IMPORTED INTERFACE)
  set_target_properties(
    GSL::GSL
    PROPERTIES
      INTERFACE_COMPILE_FEATURES "cxx_std_14"
      INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "${gsl_SOURCE_DIR}/include"
  )
endif()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you wanted to use the *short form* of `FetchContent_Populate` command. But passing *QUIET* option makes the *long form*.

Actually, the *short form* is already QUIET by default: it relies on value of `FETCHCONTENT_QUIET` cached variable, which is `ON` by default.

Simply use the *short form*:

```
FetchContent_Populate("gsl")
```

---

From the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.11/module/FetchContent.html) of `FetchContent` CMake module.

There are two forms of `FetchContent_Populate` command:

1. The **short form**, which accepts only a name of the content.

   This form **derives** all population **options** from the previous `FetchContent_Declare` call.
2. The **long form**, which accepts additional options.

   This form implies that all population options will be passed to the command **directly**.

Comment: Thank you! This is what I get for working on this so late at night.